Why do I need to manually restart NetworkManager service after each boot to "detect" the bind9 server?
Both instances are Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.4.
1. I installed bind9 on a first Ubuntu instance (IP 192.168.1.94):
/etc/default/bind9
OPTIONS="-u bind -4"

/etc/bind/named.conf.options
acl "lan" {
    192.168.1.0/24;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    recursion yes;
    listen-on { 192.168.1.0/24; };
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    allow-transfer { none; };
    dnssec-validation auto;
};

/etc/bind/named.conf.local
zone "local.lan" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.local.lan";
};

/etc/bind/zones/db.local.lan
$TTL    604800
@           IN  SOA local.lan. admin.local.lan. (
                  6     ; Serial
             604800     ; Refresh
              86400     ; Retry
            2419200     ; Expire
             604800 )   ; Negative Cache TTL

            IN  NS  local.lan.

local.lan.  IN  A   192.168.1.94 

2. Then on a second Ubuntu instance I declared the DNS server and restarted the NetworkManager service:
nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE                   CONNECTION      
wlo1             wifi      connected               WIFI
...
nmcli con mod "WIFI" ipv4.dns "192.168.1.94 192.168.1.1"
sudo service NetworkManager restart

After a few seconds I can ping local.lan which is properly resolved to 192.168.1.94.
However it stops working after each reboot even if the DNS IP still appear in the list:
ping local.lan
ping: local.lan: Name or service not known

nmcli device show wlo1
...
IP4.DNS[1]:         192.168.1.94
IP4.DNS[2]:         192.168.1.1
...

If I manually restart the NetworkManager service, everything is working well.
Update
Thank you @waltinator
dnsmasq is installed but it doesn't look to be running:
apt list --installed | grep dns
dnsmasq-base/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 2.90-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
...
systemctl list-unit-files | grep dns
<empty>

Everything is working well since I tried adding the DNS server from the GUI; it's also working from the command line.
The only difference I've noticed is there is now 3 IP4.ROUTE[3] as there was only 2 before. I will try to reproduce starting from a new instance.

Ubuntu uses systemd-dnsmasq to manage DNS. Did you disable it before you started messing around with bind?
